# Скелетная анимация Assimp (C++)

Tags: c++, анимация

Пытаюсь реализовать скелетную анимацию на C++/Vulkan с использованием библиотеки Assimp. Удалось сделать загрузку самого скелета, вроде все в порядке. Теперь есть возможность управлять каждой костью и указывать локальную трансофрмацию относительно bind трансформации. Вроде все работает не плохо. В коде это выглядит как-то так

```
    // Загрузка геометрии
    auto ar2rGeometry = vk::helpers::LoadVulkanGeometryMesh(_vkRenderer,"Ar2r-Devil-Pinky.dae", true);
    // Загрузка скелета
    auto skeleton = vk::helpers::LoadVulkanMeshSkeleton("Ar2r-Devil-Pinky.dae");

    // Добавление меша на сцену, его настройка и установка скелета
    auto Ar2r = _vkRenderer->addMeshToScene(ar2rGeometry);
    Ar2r->setPosition({0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, false);
    Ar2r->setScale({2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f});
    Ar2r->setSkeleton(std::move(skeleton));

    // Доступ к костям скелета
    auto torso = Ar2r->getSkeletonPtr()->getRootBone()->getChildrenBones()[0];
    auto leg1 = Ar2r->getSkeletonPtr()->getRootBone()->getChildrenBones()[1];
    auto leg2 = Ar2r->getSkeletonPtr()->getRootBone()->getChildrenBones()[2];
    auto neck = torso->getChildrenBones()[0];

    // Управление костями
    torso->setLocalTransform(glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::radians(45.0f),{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}));
    neck->setLocalTransform(glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::radians(-20.0f),{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}));
    leg1->setLocalTransform(glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::radians(30.0f),{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}));
    leg2->setLocalTransform(glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::radians(-30.0f),{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}));
```

Программное управление (на прямую из кода) костями вроде работает прилично. В итоге я могу деформировать меш при помощи костей.

[image: Без деформации]
[image: С деформацией]

На всякий случай приложу код вычисления матриц ветви (кости и всех ее потомков). Это метод класса SkeletonBone.

```
            void calculateBranch(bool callUpdateCallbackFunction = true, unsigned calcFlags = CalcFlags::eFullTransform | CalcFlags::eBindTransform | CalcFlags::eInverseBindTransform)
            {
                // Если у кости есть родительская кость
                if(pParentBone_ != nullptr)
                {
                    // Общая initial (bind) трансформация для кости учитывает текущую и родительскую (что в свою очередь справедливо и для родительской)
                    if(calcFlags & CalcFlags::eBindTransform)
                        totalBindTransform_ = pParentBone_->totalBindTransform_ * this->localBindTransform_;

                    // Общая полная (с учетом задаваемой) трансформация кости (смещаем на localTransform_, затем на initial, затем на общую родительскую трансформацию)
                    if(calcFlags & CalcFlags::eFullTransform)
                        totalTransform_ = pParentBone_->totalTransform_ * this->localBindTransform_ * this->localTransform_;
                }
                // Если нет родительской кости - считать кость корневой
                else
                {
                    if(calcFlags & CalcFlags::eBindTransform)
                        totalBindTransform_ = this->localBindTransform_;

                    if(calcFlags & CalcFlags::eFullTransform)
                        totalTransform_ = this->localBindTransform_ * this->localTransform_;
                }

                // Инвертированная матрица bind трансформации
                if(calcFlags & CalcFlags::eInverseBindTransform)
                    totalBindTransformInverse_ = glm::inverse(totalBindTransform_);

                // Если есть указатель на объект скелета и индекс валиден
                if(pSkeleton_ != nullptr && index_ < pSkeleton_->modelSpaceFinalTransforms_.size())
                {
                    // Итоговая матрица трансформации для точек находящихся в пространстве модели
                    // Поскольку общая трансформация кости работает с вершинами находящимися в пространстве модели,
                    // они в начале должны быть переведены в пространство кости.
                    pSkeleton_->modelSpaceFinalTransforms_[index_] = totalTransform_ * totalBindTransformInverse_;

                    // Для ситуаций, если вершины задаются сразу в пространстве кости
                    pSkeleton_->boneSpaceFinalTransforms_[index_] = totalTransform_;
                }

                // Рекурсивно выполнить для дочерних элементов (если они есть)
                if(!this->childrenBones_.empty()){
                    for(auto& childBone : this->childrenBones_){
                        childBone->calculateBranch(false, calcFlags);
                    }
                }

                // Если нужно вызвать функцию обновления UBO
                if(callUpdateCallbackFunction && this->pSkeleton_ != nullptr && this->pSkeleton_->updateCallback_ != nullptr){
                    this->pSkeleton_->updateCallback_();
                }
            }
```

И также приложу код функции загрузки информации о скелете:

```
    /**
     * Загрузка скелета из файла 3D-моделей
     * @param filename Имя файла в папке Models
     * @return Объект скелета
     */
    vk::scene::UniqueSkeleton LoadVulkanMeshSkeleton(const std::string &filename)
    {
        // Итоговый скелет
        vk::scene::UniqueSkeleton skeleton = std::make_unique<vk::scene::Skeleton>();

        // Полный путь к файлу
        auto path = ::tools::ExeDir().append("..\\Models\\").append(filename);

        // Импортер Assimp
        Assimp::Importer importer;

        // Получить сцену
        const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path.c_str(),
                aiProcess_Triangulate |
                aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
                //aiProcess_PreTransformVertices |
                aiProcess_FlipWindingOrder |
                aiProcess_PopulateArmatureData
        );

        // Если не удалось загрузить
        if(scene == nullptr){
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Can't load geometry from (").append(path).append(")").c_str());
        }

        // Если нет геометрических мешей
        if(!scene->HasMeshes()){
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Can't find any geometry meshes from (").append(path).append(")").c_str());
        }

        // Первый меш сцены
        auto pFirstMesh = scene->mMeshes[0];

        // Если у меша есть кости
        if(pFirstMesh->HasBones())
        {
            // Инициализировать скелет
            skeleton = std::make_unique<vk::scene::Skeleton>(pFirstMesh->mNumBones);

            // Ассоциативный массив костей Assimp
            std::unordered_map<std::string, aiBone*> bones{};
            // Ассоциативный массив индексов костей
            std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> indices{};

            // Пройтись по костям скелета и заполнить ассоциативные массив костей и индексов для доступа по именам
            for(size_t i = 0; i < pFirstMesh->mNumBones; i++)
            {
                bones[pFirstMesh->mBones[i]->mName.C_Str()] = pFirstMesh->mBones[i];
                indices[pFirstMesh->mBones[i]->mName.C_Str()] = i;
            }

            // Установить значение корневой кости скелета
            auto rootBone = pFirstMesh->mBones[0];
            skeleton->getRootBone()->setLocalBindTransform(ToGlmMat4(rootBone->mNode->mTransformation));

            // Добавление дочерних костей
            RecursivePopulateSkeleton(pFirstMesh->mBones[0]->mName.C_Str(), skeleton->getRootBone(), bones, indices, scene);
        }

        // Отдать скелет
        return skeleton;
    }

    /**
     * Рекурсивное заполнение данных скелета
     * @param assimpBoneName Наименование кости assimp
     * @param bone Текущая кость
     * @param assimpBones Ассоциативный массив костей assimp (ключ - имя кости)
     * @param assimpBoneIndices Ассоциативный массив индексов костей (ключ - имя кости)
     */
    static inline void RecursivePopulateSkeleton(const std::string& assimpBoneName,
                                   const vk::scene::SkeletonBonePtr& bone,
                                   const std::unordered_map<std::string, aiBone*>& assimpBones,
                                   const std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t>& assimpBoneIndices,
                                   const aiScene* scene)
    {
        // Получить текущую кость assimp
        auto assimpBone = assimpBones.at(assimpBoneName);

        // Если у кости есть потомки
        if(assimpBone->mNode->mNumChildren > 0)
        {
            // Пройтись по ним
            for(size_t i = 0; i < assimpBone->mNode->mNumChildren; i++)
            {
                // Получить необходимые данные о потомке
                auto childNode = assimpBone->mNode->mChildren[i];

                // Если такого индекса кости не обнаружено - пропуск итерации
                if(assimpBoneIndices.find(childNode->mName.C_Str()) == assimpBoneIndices.end())
                    continue;

                // Индекс кости
                auto childIndex = assimpBoneIndices.at(childNode->mName.C_Str());

                // Добавить нового потомка в текущую кость
                auto child = bone->addChildBone(childIndex, ToGlmMat4(childNode->mTransformation),glm::mat4(1.0f));

                // Рекурсивно выполнить эту функцию для потомка
                RecursivePopulateSkeleton(childNode->mName.C_Str(), child, assimpBones, assimpBoneIndices, scene);
            }
        }
    }
```

Как я и писал выше - загрузка скелета работает вменяемо. В качестве bind трансформаций, при загрузке я использую матрицу mTransformation у узлов (node) Assimp. В итоге все загружается корректно, меш отображается в bind позе. Для каждой отдельной кости можно устанавливать дополнительную (локальную относительно bind) анимацию, и всё опять же, корректно работает.

**И тут я решил попробовать загрузить информацию об анимации при помощи Assimp из Collada файла.**

Судя по всевозможным туториалам, трансформации которые находятся в ключевых кадрах должны находится в ЛОКАЛЬНОМ пространстве костей (относительно родительской кости). Я попробовал загрузить эту информацию. Это я делал примерно так:

```
        // Пройтись по набору анимаций сцены
        for(size_t i = 0; i < scene->mNumAnimations; i++)
        {
            // Указатель на анимацию Assimp
            auto pAiAnimation = scene->mAnimations[i];
            // Кол-во ключевых кадров (считаем что у всех каналов одинаковое кол-во ключевых кадров)
            auto keyframesCount = pAiAnimation->mChannels[0]->mNumRotationKeys;

            // Продолжительность в тиках (1 тик - 1 м/с)
            auto duration = static_cast<float>(pAiAnimation->mDuration);

            // Создать анимацию
            auto animation = std::make_shared<vk::scene::SkeletonAnimation>(duration);

            // Пройтись по ключевым кадрам
            for(size_t f = 0; f < keyframesCount; f++)
            {
                // Время кадра
                auto frameTime = static_cast<float>(pAiAnimation->mChannels[0]->mRotationKeys[f].mTime);
                // Создать кадр
                vk::scene::SkeletonAnimation::Keyframe keyframe(frameTime,totalBones);

                // Пройтись по всем костям
                for(size_t j = 0; j < pAiAnimation->mNumChannels; j++)
                {
                    // Указатель на канал (кость) Assimp
                    auto pAiBoneChannel = pAiAnimation->mChannels[j];

                    // Получить индекс кости
                    auto boneIndex = indices.at(pAiBoneChannel->mNodeName.C_Str());
                    
                    // Установить трансформацию кости в кадре
                    keyframe.setBonePosition(boneIndex,{
                            ToGlmVec3(pAiBoneChannel->mPositionKeys[f].mValue),
                            ToGlmQuat(pAiBoneChannel->mRotationKeys[f].mValue),
                            ToGlmVec3(pAiBoneChannel->mScalingKeys[f].mValue)
                    });
                }

                // Добавить ключевой кадр
                animation->addKeyFrame(keyframe);
            }

            // Добавить анимацию
            animations.push_back(animation);
        }
```

Методы конвертации из Assimp в GLM:

```
    static inline glm::vec3 ToGlmVec3(const aiVector3D &v) { return glm::vec3(v.x, v.y, v.z); }
    static inline glm::vec2 ToGlmVec2(const aiVector3D &v) { return glm::vec2(v.x, v.y); }
    static inline glm::quat ToGlmQuat(const aiQuaternion &q) { return glm::quat(q.w, q.x, q.y, q.z); }
    static inline glm::mat4 ToGlmMat4(const aiMatrix4x4 &m) { return glm::transpose(glm::make_mat4(&m.a1)); }
    static inline glm::mat4 ToGlmMat4(const aiMatrix3x3 &m) { return glm::transpose(glm::make_mat3(&m.a1)); }
```

Но это была просто загрузка. Далее я попытался просто взять данные по трансформациям костей из первого же кадра.

```
            // Получить положения костей для кадра 0
            auto bonePositions = this->skeletonAnimation_->getKeyFrames()[0].getBonePositions();

            // Пройтись по положениям костей
            for(size_t i = 0; i < bonePositions.size(); i++)
            {
                // Получить кость скелета
                auto bone = this->getSkeletonPtr()->getBoneByIndex(i);

                // Получить матрицы трансформации
                auto scaleM = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f),bonePositions[i].scaling);
                auto rotM = glm::toMat4(bonePositions[i].rotation);
                auto translateM = glm::transpose(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),bonePositions[i].location));

                // Установить локальную трансформацию
                bone->setLocalTransform(rotM, false);
            }
            
            // Пересчитать матрицы
            this->getSkeletonPtr()->getRootBone()->calculateBranch(true);
```

Как видно из кода, я решил для начала попробовать только с поворотами (по сути там только они менялись) В итоге я получил что-то неадекватное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался применить и другие матрицы (смещения и масштабирования) но толку это не дало. Я пытался конвертировать кватернион в обычные углы эйлера и смотреть, какие там значения - и значения там были совершенно непонятно откуда взявшиеся.

В чем моя ошибка? Может я что-то не знаю об особенностях Assimp? В каком пространстве хранятся данные, которые отдает Assimp (mPositionKeys, mRotationKeys, mScalingKeys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Всё дело было в том, что трансформацию, которую assimp отдает для анимации уже содержит в себе локальную bind трансформацию кости. То есть, в своем коде:

```
totalTransform_ = pParentBone_->totalTransform_ * this->localBindTransform_ * this->localTransform_;
```

Я ожидал от Assimp получить именно `localTransform_`, а по факту получал `localBindTransform_ * localTransform_`.

Проблему решило умножение на инвертированную матрицу bind трансформации.

```
                    // Получить индекс кости и саму кость
                    auto boneIndex = indices.at(pAiBoneChannel->mNodeName.C_Str());
                    auto bone = pFirstMesh->mBones[boneIndex];

                    // Матрица локальной трансформации кости (включающая локальную bind трансформацию)
                    aiMatrix4x4 boneTransformWithBind(pAiBoneChannel->mScalingKeys[f].mValue,pAiBoneChannel->mRotationKeys[f].mValue,pAiBoneChannel->mPositionKeys[f].mValue);
                    // Матрица локальной bind трансформации
                    aiMatrix4x4 boneLocalBindTransform = bone->mNode->mTransformation;
                    // Матрица ТОЛЬКО локальной трансформации
                    aiMatrix4x4 boneTransform = boneLocalBindTransform.Inverse() * boneTransformWithBind;

                    // Декомпозиция матрицы на отдельные компоненты
                    glm::vec3 scale;
                    glm::quat rotate;
                    glm::vec3 translate;
                    glm::vec3 skew;
                    glm::vec4 perspective;
                    glm::decompose(ToGlmMat4(boneTransform),scale,rotate,translate,skew,perspective);

                    // Установить трансформацию кости в кадре
                    keyframe.setBonePosition(boneIndex,{
                            translate,
                            rotate,
                            scale
                    });
```

Может быть кому-то это пригодится.